# Describe curves by words

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, curves

I am trying to describe the general aspect of the following curves [image]

My ideas:

1. The curves are continuous, and defined for positive values of x, and giving negative values.
2. Have logarithmic growth (increase logarithmically)
3. The curves become flatten as they approaches the x axis.

Does any one have other ideas for  describing such curves?

Please feel free to point me if the ideas I mentioned are not suitable for describing the curves.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you should be plotting this data on a [log scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-log_plot) where they will likely look like more or less straight lines which are much easier to compare and interpret.

Comment: If the curves were smoother, without wobbles, then they might be described as *concave increasing*; some people (not me) call this *concave down increasing*

Comment: @DerekElkins  Thaks for you suggestion , however How would I use the log scale  when  having negative values of the outcome?

Comment: You use a [lin-log scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LinLogScale.svg), i.e. make the x-axis the log scale.  Note how in that image it turns the logarithm function into a straight line.